# How to use watch in gruntjs to assign multiple tasks to multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, rake, less, gruntjs

I'm trying to do this (pseudo code):

```
watch

files: fileset1 (for example: *.less), fileset2 (for example: *.mustache)
tasks: 'less','rake'
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the [Grunt jQuery example](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt-jquery-example/blob/master/grunt.js):

```
watch: {
   files: ['*.less', '*.mustache'],
   tasks: 'less rake'
}
```

Comment: Is it really working in 0.4?
Tried it - doesn't seem to work. Looks like this config starts two tasks on each change.

Comment: It's from their example code; yes it works; I use dozens of variations. I can't comment on 0.4's behavior as that is yet unreleased; the current stable version is 0.3.10.